# Android/Java. Событие при клике на иконке Action Bar'a а не пункта?

Tags: android, actionbar, события, icon

Есть Action Bar (стандартный) с иконкой при клике на которой появляется меню (пункты меню).. ну как обычно..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли обработчик стандартный этого события? как сделать такое?

Answer (score 2):

menu.xml

```
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_settings"
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always"/> // всегда на панели

</menu>
```

метод в MainActivity.class

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WOW!, this button do something", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: почти, но там при удержании всплывает title пункт..а если убрать то Menu items should specify a title -- как вообще убрать ?

Comment: Это совершенно другой вопрос, советую создать его будет много кому интересен.

Answer (score 1):

Предложу такой <s>**костыль**</s> вариант

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    doSmth();
}
```

**PS**: вызывается так же при старте, так что первый вызов необходимо игнорить)